# Dirichlet problem on rectangle with nonhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I want to solve the following problem in Dirichlet Problem:

Let $D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2  : 0 < x < a; 0 < y < b\}$ be a rectangle with boundary   $\partial D$. I want to solve Laplace equation with following the boundary condition:

$$u(x, y) = x + y; \quad (x, y) \in  \partial  D$$

To apply method of separation of variables, I would need homogeneous boundary condition ([reference](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~peirce/M257_316_2012_Lecture_24.pdf)), so is this boundary condition homogeneous? Or do I have to break it down for each edge and use superposition to get to the solution? Or is there any other method to solve it?

Comment: You can put formulas between `$`.. for example,  `$ \Bbb R^2 $` produces $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Also, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Because $x+y$ is harmonic on the whole rectangle, you can just read off a solution: your solution is just $x+y$ extended over the whole rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: the separation of variables in a rectangle requires homogeneous boundary conditions on two opposing sides of the rectangle. When we don't have that, one approach is to come up with a harmonic function $w$ that satisfies two of the boundary conditions; then look for $v=u-w$, which has homogeneous boundary conditions.

How to come up with $w$ depends on the boundary conditions. Polynomials are good because we can play with undetermined coefficients if needed. Basically, you start with the formula you have ($x+y$), check if this is already a harmonic function, and if not, think of something to add to it while preserving some of the boundary values.

In this case, the process of over quickly: $x+y$ is harmonic.

Comment: I understood the answer for this one, but don't know what to do when u is not harmonic. Like, what to do if $$ u= x^2 + y^2  $$ ?

Comment: Then it's harder. Look for solution in the form $u=v+w$ where $v$ has the required boundary values on horizontal sides and zero on vertical sides; $w$ has required values on vertical sides and zero on horizontal. For both $v$ and $w$ the separation of variables works.

Comment: Could $$ u = x^2 + y^2 - x(x-a) - y(y-b) $$ work as a solution here?

Comment: No, it does not satisfy the boundary conditions. Generally, the exercises in PDE books are chosen so that the method the book describes works reasonably well. Do not expect the same methods to perform as well on problems that do not come from the textbook

Comment: Could you mention some method that would work here?

Comment: [I already did](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035093/dirichlet-problem-on-rectangle-with-nonhomogeneous-boundary-conditions/1035266?noredirect=1#comment2110200_1035266)